# What are the best browser based administration tools for Linux?

Tags: linux, web-applications

Looking for recommendations the best comprehensive browser based administration tool for administering a Linux machine.  Ideally this would be distribution agnostic.  This could also be an "appliance" type product that would administer multiple machines on network.

This is marked community wiki.  Give your answer preferably one product per answer and vote up packages that you recommend also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) which offers a comprehensive set of [administration tools for everything from](http://www.webmin.com/standard.html) process management, apache, BIND DNS, bandwidth monitoring, command shell, DHCP server, various mail servers, RAID, IP tunnelling, MYSQL (etc etc!) to a java based file manager - plus a shed load of [3rd party modules](http://www.webmin.com/cgi-bin/search_third.cgi?modules=1). It's available in RPM, deb, TAR, and solaris formats and can administer multiple machines as a "cluster". [Many languages are supported](http://www.webmin.com/lang.html) too.

Comment: Just watch out for security ! Webmin should not be accessible by anyone on the Internet as in really not at all.

Comment: Webmin really is your best option, IMHO. We use it on all of our servers.

Answer (score 3):

I use ebox on a server that need such an interface. It's a bit young when compared to webmin. It's worth a peek:

http://trac.ebox-platform.com/wiki/Document/FAQ/HowEboxDiffersFromWebmin

The main reason for choosing ebox being that box runs debian.

Comment: +1 for suggesting an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There are others which you can explore..

1. [ISPConfig](http://www.ispconfig.org/)
2. [Ajenti](http://ajenti.org/)
3. [ZPanel](http://www.zpanelcp.com/)